# Mock a jUnit test using powermockito

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I am trying to mock the following functionality

```
public class ServerConnection{
        public ServerConnection(ClientConnection cn) {
            super(cn);
        }

    public void setUrl(String url) {      
                this.url = URLUtil.processURL(url);
                try {
                    URL dst = new URL(this.url);
                    InputStream is = dst.openStream();
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    while(scanner.hasNextLine())
                        sb.append(scanner.nextLine()).append("\n");


                    if (validate(sb.toString())) {
                       --------
                    } else {    }
                    is.close();
                    scanner.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }        
        }

    private boolean validate(String content) {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            Boolean isJsonValid = false;
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
              --------
              //json validation goes here
            } catch (Exception e) {          
            }
            return isJsonValid;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
        if(id == null)
        this.id = 0;
        else
        this.id = id;
        }
}
```

PowerMockito Junit code

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({PathTest.class })
public class URLTest {
 ServerConnection sc ;
 String URL = "http://test.com";

  @Before
     public void setUp() throws Throwable{              
             ClientConnection con =PathTest.getCon();  // Here getCon() is a static method
             sc = new ServerConnection(con);
             sc.setId(1000); 
     }

@Test
    public void testName() throws Throwable {       

        String expectedResponse = "test";
        URL url = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);
        HttpURLConnection connection = PowerMockito.mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
        InputStream inputStream = PowerMockito.mock(InputStream.class);
        Scanner scanner = PowerMockito.mock(Scanner.class);

        PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withArguments(URL).thenReturn(url);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Scanner.class).withArguments(inputStream).thenReturn(scanner);
        PowerMockito.when(scanner.useDelimiter("\\A")).thenReturn(scanner);

        PowerMockito.when(url.openConnection()).thenReturn(connection);

        // Response code mocked here
        PowerMockito.when(connection.getResponseCode()).thenReturn(200);

        PowerMockito.when(connection.getInputStream()).thenReturn(inputStream);
        PowerMockito.when(scanner.hasNext()).thenReturn(true);
        PowerMockito.when(scanner.next()).thenReturn(expectedResponse);

        sc.setUrl(URL);
    }
}
```

While Iam executing this I observed following error message

```
URLTest
com.objects.URLTest
testName(com.objects.URLTest)
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)

    at javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassObject(Desc.java:43)

    at javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassType(Desc.java:152)

    at javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:122)

    at javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:78)

    at com.objects.PathTest.getCon(TargetPathTest.java:24)

    at com.objects.URLTest.setUp(URLTest.java:41)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:133)

    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)

    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)

    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)

    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)

    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)

    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)

    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)

    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)

    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)

    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)

    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)

    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)

    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)

    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)

    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)

    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)

    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)

    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)

    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   

    ... 38 more
```

Comment: Can you post the code of PathTest? It looks like error is coming from PathTest.getCon(). Did you call mockstatic on classes with static methods that need to be mocked.

Comment: did you try removing pieces of code until the NPE went away? this is a good way to isolate what is throwing the exception.

Comment: Unrelated: you have several empty catch blocks in your code under test. Seriously: that is a **no go**. Dont worry writing unit tests for code that **ignores** errors at runtime.

Comment: Your answer is more informative, Thank you ...Ofcource I accepted the answer. Thumbs up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many things wrong with this code.

The first technical answer is: you seem to not know what you are doing. You have `@PrepareForTest({PathTest.class })` which indicates that you intend to mock a static method of that class.

But then you aren't doing what is necessary to mock a static method in that class. Simply follow their [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockstatic) step by step. I also think that the URL class is final, so you would have to prepare-annotate that class as well, in order for it be used with whenNew()!

But then: you should avoid mocking URL or URL connection objects. Simply use some sort of dependency injection, and make sure you can **pass** some mocked instance into your code under test, for example using the @InjectMocks annotation of Mockito. From there, you might also avoid using a **static** method.

Long story short: your production code is badly written, and your unit test is (honestly) plain horrible. You should seriously step back here, and throw that stuff away. Then re-think your production code to **not** use `new` directly, and to not rely on *static* methods. By doing so, you can get rid of PowerMockito, you go with ordinary Mockito (well, you need to enable mocking of final classes). But rest assured: there is no point in using PowerMock(ito) unless you absolutely have to.

And then: don't "invent" mocking code. Read tutorials, and follow them step by step. You are mocking like *everything* in your test case, but you should do the exact opposite: you only mock things when there is absolutely no other way to test your code. And you absolutely do not make a method static when that breaks your ability to reasonably unit test your code.

( static has its place, but when it gets in your way, you are doing the wrong thing ! )